# What is the best way to access the last entered key in a default dict in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a default dict of dicts whose primary key is a timestamp in the string form 'YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS.' The keys are entered sequentially. How do I access the last entered key or the key with the latest timestamp?

Comment: As I mentioned in the title, I want to access the last entered key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module if you simply need to access the last item entered. If, however, you need to maintain continuous sorting, you need to use a different data structure entirely, or at least an auxiliary one for the purposes of indexing.

Edit: I would add that, if accessing the final element is an operation that you have to do very rarely, it may be sufficient simply to sort the dict's keys and select the maximum. If you have to do this frequently, however, repeatedly sorting would become prohibitively expensive. Depending on how your code works, the simplest approach would probably be to simply maintain a single variable that, at any given point, contains the last key added and/or the maximum value added (i.e., is updated with each subsequent addition to the dict). If you want to maintain a record of additions that extends beyond just the last item, however, and don't require continuous sorting, an `OrderedDict` is ideal.

Comment: Could probably use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/0.3.0 for continuous sorting and decent time complexities.

Comment: @IoanAlexandruCucu, yeah, that's certainly a possibility. If one were limited to the standard libraries, another option would be to use a list of keys as an auxiliary data structure for indexing into the dict, making use of the `bisect` module for maintaining the list's ordering.

Comment: What if I'm using a default dict?

Comment: @idealistikz, see my edit, it should answer your question. If not, then I need more information about your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) rather than a built-in dict

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
>>> import time
>>> data ={'20120627 21:20:23':'first','20120627 21:20:40':'last'}
>>> latest = lambda d: time.strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S',max(map(lambda x: time.strptime(x,'%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'),d.keys())))
>>> data[latest(data)]
'last'
```

but it probably would be slow on large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know who entered the last (according to time of entrance) see the example below:

```
import datetime

format='%Y%m%d %H:%M'

Dict={'20010203 12:00':'Dave',
      '20000504 03:00':'Pete',
      '20020825 23:00':'kathy',
      '20030102 01:00':'Ray'}

myDict={}

for key,val in Dict.iteritems():

    TIME= str(datetime.datetime.strptime(key,format))

    myDict[TIME]= val

myDict=sorted(myDict.iteritems(), key=lambda (TIME,v): (TIME))

print myDict[-1]
```